# R: TermDocumentMatrix - Error while creating

Tags: r, term-document-matrix, mclapply

I am trying to get twitter data and create a wordcloud but my code is giving error while creating TermDocumentMatrix. My code is as below

```
twitter_search_data <- searchTwitter(searchString = text_to_search
                                    ,n = 500)

twitter_search_text <- sapply(twitter_search_data
                             ,function(x) x$getText())

twitter_search_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(twitter_search_text))

twitter_search_corpus <- tm_map(twitter_search_corpus, stripWhitespace, lazy = TRUE)

twitter_search_corpus <- tm_map(twitter_search_corpus, content_transformer(tolower), lazy = TRUE)

twitter_search_corpus <- tm_map(twitter_search_corpus, PlainTextDocument,lazy = TRUE)    

twitter_search_corpus <- tm_map(twitter_search_corpus, removePunctuation, lazy = TRUE)

twitter_search_corpus <- tm_map(twitter_search_corpus, removeNumbers, lazy = TRUE)

twitter_search_corpus <- tm_map(twitter_search_corpus, removeWords, c("the", "this", "The", "This", stopwords('english')), lazy = TRUE)

twitter_search_corpus <- tm_map(twitter_search_corpus, stemDocument, lazy = TRUE)

# Create Document Term Matrix 
tdm <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(twitter_search_corpus
                                   ,control=list(wordLengths=c(3,Inf))
                                   ))
```

There are no errors before creating TermDocumentMatrix. The error I get is as below

> Warning in mclapply(x$content[i], function(d) tm_reduce(d, x$lazy$maps)) :
>       scheduled core 1 encountered error in user code, all values of the job  will be affected
>       Warning in mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
>       scheduled core 1 encountered error in user code, all values of the job will be affected
>       Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "try-error"
>       Stack trace (innermost first):
>       74: FUN
>       73: lapply
>       72: setNames
>       71: as.list.VCorpus
>       70: as.list
>       69: lapply
>       68: meta.VCorpus
>       67: meta
>       66: TermDocumentMatrix.VCorpus
>       65: TermDocumentMatrix
>       64: as.matrix
>       63: observeEventHandler
>        1: runApp

I have already added `lazy = TRUE` and `content_transformer(tolower)` but still the error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with placement of

```
twitter_search_corpus <- tm_map(twitter_search_corpus, stripWhitespace, lazy = TRUE)
```

After removing punctuation, numbers and words whitespaces were inserted in the text. So the above code to remove whitespaces need to be the last statement before creating TermDocumentMatrix.